# How to show and hide the particular div, when we click on particular link on that div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Node: Please see the demo**
All div are generated dynamically, and having same class `class="bucket"`. This div had one more div inside `class="restPart"` rest part, which will hide, when page load first time.

What I want, I have more than one div,
1. Each divs **hides the rest part**, when page load **first time**.
2. Each div are diving into two part, one part will **always show** and **rest part will not show**.
3. Rest part will appear only when we click the link "**show more**",
4. When div are fully shown It will show link "**show less**", when we click on it, will hide the rest part.
5. This should work only for **one div on which we are clicking**, other divs should be unaware.

**_data_grid.html**

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $("#restPart").hide();
    $('#grid_content').on('click','.more', function(){
        //$("#restPart").show();
         $("div").children("div").show();
         $("#showRest").hide();

    });
    $('#grid_content').on('click','.less', function(){
        //$("#restPart").hide();
        $("#showRest").show();
         $(this).closest("div").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

```css
#grid_content {
    overflow: hidden; clear: both;
  }
  #grid_content .bucket {
    width: 290px; float: left; margin: 0 0 48px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #262626;
     background: $gray-lighter;

  }



  #grid_content .bucket ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  }

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="grid_content">
    <!--1st -->
    <div class="bucket">

        ... Content of visible part of bucket...                
        <a href="#" class="more" id="showRest">Show More.</a>
            <!--Below is the rest part when we click on the above link, Showrest it will show-->
        <div class="restPart" id="restPart">
            ... Content of Rest Part and click on the Show Less It will hide this div...
            <a href="#" class="less" id="showless">Show Less.</a> 
        </div> 

    </div>


    <!--2nd -->
    <div class="bucket">

        ... Content of visible part of bucket...                
        <a href="#" class="more" id="showRest">Show More.</a>

        <!--Below is the rest part when we click on the above link, Showrest it will show-->
        <div class="restPart" id="restPart">

            ... Content of Rest Part and click on the Show Less It will hide this div...

            <a href="#" class="less" id="showless">Show Less.</a> 
        </div> 

    </div>
</section>
```

Please see the following figure, If I click on **show content** on 1st div then It will show rest of 1st div on other will not show, If I click on 2nd div then It will show the rest 2nd div, no other div will show.

**What  I want**

In the like following figures, more div will be generated **dynamically**, previously all will hide, when I click on **first div** show the rest content, but rest will not show, please see the **figure 2**,

[image]
**Figure 1**

[image]
**Figure 2**

Comment: what is `#showRest` ?

Comment: @saru95, Thanks for response, #showRest is id of link when we click on this it will show the rest past of div..

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code . I think this is what you want to achieve .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bucket .restPart').hide();
    $('.more').show();
    $('.less').hide();
    $('.more').click(function() {
        $('.more').toggle() ;
        $(this).parent().next('.restPart').show();
        $('.less').toggle() ;
    });
    $('.less').click(function() {
        $('.less').toggle() ;
        $(this).parents('.restPart').hide();
        $('.more').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: its not working, It is not woking, Your javascript only hide, the rest first div and others divs are not hiding the rest part. And Also I click the show rest part, I show the rest part but, I remove the links show less part, which is used for hide the rest.

Comment: yes , but invain, Let me tell you ur working code, 1. When first time page lode it hide the only one div, but other div are not hiding the rest part, 2. When I click on the show more then It is show the rest part of first part but It also forcing the rest part of other div..

Comment: I get what, you're saying. Try this .

Comment: What I want, I have more than one div, each div hides the rest part, when page load fist time. Each div are diving into two part, one part will always show and rest part will not show. It appears only when we click the link "show this content", when we div has one more link "show less", which will hide the rest content when we click on it. 3. This should work only for one div on which we are clicking, other divs should be unaware.

Comment: I have given my final shot. Try it . please. Sorry, if it doesnt work !

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect using straightforward Javascript (rather than jQuery).

```js
function showRestPart() {
var restPart = document.getElementById('restPart');
restPart.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideRestPart() {
var restPart = document.getElementById('restPart');
restPart.style.display = 'none';
}

function initialiseRestPart() {
var restPart = document.getElementById('restPart');
restPart.style.display = 'none';

var showMore = document.getElementById('showMore');
showMore.addEventListener('click',showRestPart,false);

var showLess = document.getElementById('showLess');
showLess.addEventListener('click',hideRestPart,false);
}

window.onload = initialiseRestPart();
```

```html
<div class="bucket">

... Content of visible part of bucket...

<a href="#" id="showMore">Show More.</a>

<div id="restPart">

... Content of Rest Part...

<a href="#" id="showLess">Show Less.</a> 
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, In your answer you have only one div but I have more than one divs..

Comment: Yes, for the sake of a simple example I have only one div in my answer. Do you want to take it from here or do you need more assistance?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the Ids.
In a file, two elements shouldn't have the same id.

Apart from that your code seems fine, (more or less).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".restPart").hide();
    $('#grid_content').on('click', '.more', function() {
        $(this).nextAll(".restPart:first").show();
    });
    $('#grid_content').on('click', '.less', function() {
      $(this).closest("div").hide();
    });
});
```

and the HTML :

```
<section id="grid_content">
    <!--1st div generated by dynamically -->
    <div class="bucket">
        <ul>Name: </ul>
        <ul>Address: </ul>
        <ul>Job:</ul>
        <a href="#" class="more">Show More.</a>
        <!--Below is the rest part when we click on the above link, Showrest it will show-->
        <div class="restPart">
            <ul>Quealification: </ul>
            <ul>College: </ul>
            <ul>Country+:</ul>
            <a href="#" class="less">Show Less.</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--2nd div generated by dynamically-->
    <div class="bucket">
        <ul>Name: </ul>
        <ul>Address: </ul>
        <ul>Job:</ul>
        <a href="#" class="more">Show More.</a>
        <!--Below is the rest part when we click on the above link, Showrest it will show-->
        <div class="restPart">
            <ul>Quealification: </ul>
            <ul>College: </ul>
            <ul>Country+:</ul>
            <a href="#" class="less">Show Less.</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--3rd div generated by dynamically-->
    <div class="bucket">
        <ul>Name: </ul>
        <ul>Address: </ul>
        <ul>Job:</ul>
        <a href="#" class="more">Show More.</a>
        <!--Below is the rest part when we click on the above link, Showrest it will show-->
        <div class="restPart">
            <ul>Quealification: </ul>
            <ul>College: </ul>
            <ul>Country+:</ul>
            <a href="#" class="less">Show Less.</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think this should do what you want